# What permissions are required when creating a new IAM policy for S3 uploads?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, flutter, amazon-iam

I am developing a flutter application where I can upload images to Amazon S3. For this, I need to get an `IAM Access Keys` and its `Access Key ID`and a `Secret access key`.

So I created a new `IAM User` and tried creating a new policy, where it only allows

1. Uploading files
2. Reading Files

I do not need it to create/delete buckets etc.

It didnt work. I noticed when I give `full s3 access` I can upload without an issue, so probably I missed some permissions when creating the policy. Below are my permissions.

[image]

[image]
What are the list of permissions I need to provide for my new access policy which provides the restricted access as mentioned above?

Here it is in JSON

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

**UPDATE**

Below is my s3 bucket settings

```
**Properties**
Events 0 Active notifications
Versioning Suspended
MFA delete Disabled
Logging Disabled
Static web hosting Disabled
Tags 0 Tags
Requester pays Disabled
Object lock Disabled
Transfer acceleration Disabled

**Permissions**
Owner xxxxxx
Block public access Disabled
Bucket policy No
Access control list 1 Grantees
CORS configuration No

**Management**
Lifecycle Disabled
Cross-region replication Disabled
Analytics Disabled
Inventory Disabled
Metrics Disabled
```

Comment: Please post your IAM policy to see what you may have missed.

Comment: @Asdfg: Done. Please check the update.

Comment: That is not IAM policy document.

Comment: @Asdfg: Well that's all what I did. Ticking the check boxes. When I tick all check boxes it works.

Comment: @Asdfg: If you are looking for the JSON version, I have updated the question.

Comment: Does you bucket have versioning enabled? What error message are you getting?

Comment: @Asdfg: Versioning not enabled. I am using a flutter package for this puspose so I don't get error message except a notice saying `upload failed`.

Comment: @Asdfg: When I enabled the following it started to work, but I am sure not all of them are required. -   `"s3:PutAccountPublicAccessBlock",
                "s3:PutBucketPublicAccessBlock", "s3:DeleteBucketPolicy", "s3:ObjectOwnerOverrideToBucketOwner",,  
                "s3:PutObjectVersionAcl",
                "s3:PutBucketAcl",
                "s3:PutBucketPolicy", "s3:PutBucketVersioning",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl",`

Comment: I think you just need to add `s3:PutObjectAcl` in addition to `"s3:PutObject", "s3:GetObject", "s3:DeleteObject"`

Comment: @Asdfg: ahh, there we go. Thanks, please provide your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to add `s3:PutObjectAcl` in addition to `"s3:PutObject", "s3:GetObject", "s3:DeleteObject"`

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```